# in node/stylus: get stylus to compile to different dirctory

Tags: node.js, express, stylus

original `.styl` files in `.../node/` directory

wish to compile `.css` to `.../nginx/` directory

```
app.use( stylus.middleware({
  src: __dirname + '/node/www',
  dest: __dirname + '/node/www',
  //=src: req.basepath,
  //=dest: req.basepath,
  compile: function(str, path) {
      return stylus(str)
      .set('filename', path)
      .set('compress', true)
      .use(nib());
  }
}) );
```

if I change `dest: __dirname + '/node/www'`, to `dest: __dirname + '/nginx/www'` it bombs

don't quite understand how this is supposed to work

---

solved: was compiling ok.  in `express`, `stylus` compiles in one step and then is served as a static file in a second step.  this is different than `jade`, which is compiled and served in the same step - therein lay my confusion.

so using `stylus` in `express`, need to set the correct directory in the `static` step if `stylus` is compiling to a different directory.

Comment: That snippet looks OK based on the docs. Does `__dirname + '/node/nginx'` actually exist? What is the full error message you get when "it bombs"?

Comment: @PeterLyons - sorry late getting back.  the program simply hangs.  both '.../node/www/' and '.../nginx/www' exist.  my static stylus compiler writes files to '.../nginx/www', but cannot get the dynamic compiler pointed there.

Comment: Bit late, but if it helps, I just answered a question about the SASS middleware which uses the same confusing path handling as the Stylus middleware: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15675972/893780

Comment: @robertklep  - thanks for keeping in mind.  will check it out

Comment: @robertklep - re-did all and works correctly as you had anticipated - thanks