# node-sass not compiling with node / express

Tags: node.js, express, sass

I'm trying to get node-sass working with express, and I simply can't get it to do any compiling at all. This is my app.js file:

```
var express = require('express')
  , sass = require('node-sass')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  app.use(sass.middleware({
     src: __dirname + '/public/sass',
     dest: __dirname + '/public/stylesheets', 
     debug: true
  }));
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here'));
  app.use(express.session());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

I have `public/sass` and `public/stylesheets`, yet no matter what `.scss` files I place in the sass directory nothing is getting compiled. Is there something more that I need to run beyond `node app.js`?

I'm really close to giving up and just install the sass gem and keeping an extra tab open to watch the directory.

Answer (score 8):

It's as confusing as the Stylus middleware (by which it is inspired, it says).

The folder structure of `src` should mimic the eventual structure of the destination *and* the path you're using to request the CSS file. If you want your CSS files to be stored like this:

```
./public/stylesheets/app.css
```

And the URL to access the file will be:

```
http://.../stylesheets/app.css
```

You need to configure the middleware like this:

```
app.use(sass.middleware({
   src:   __dirname + '/public/sass',
   dest:  __dirname + '/public',
   debug: true
}));
```

And your SASS folder structure like this:

```
./public/sass/stylesheets/app.scss
```

I believe it works like this:

- take the path of the HTTP request: `/stylesheets/app.css`
- to find the SCSS file, concatenate the URL path to `src` and replace extension: `./public/sass/stylesheets/app.scss`
- for the destination, concatenate the URL path to `dest`: `./public/stylesheets/app.css`

Comment: That makes sense, but sadly it still doesn't work. SCSS files still never get compiled.

Comment: I'm using *almost* your code ([gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/5264130)) and that works just fine (including re-rendering when the SCSS file is changed). Perhaps a permission problem?

Comment: That's really odd. I have the same setup and directory structure, but it's simply not working for me. Oh well. I'll just continue using my compass gem.

Comment: Are you trying SASS files or SCSS files?  node-sass can only handle SCSS files, because libsass, the C library sitting under it, only does SCSS.  It's probably a hefty project to add SASS functionality to libsass, and everyone's time is short.

Comment: I'm also doing something similar, and it's just not reaching the "render" stage: https://gist.github.com/CLUSTERfoo/7585484

Comment: I am using Stylus, and this fixed my problem. NEVER would have figured out how they were handling paths!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try using the prefix option:

```
app.use(sass.middleware({
    src: __dirname + '/public/sass',
    dest: __dirname + '/public', 
    prefix:  '/stylesheets'
    debug: true
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having similar issues getting the node-sass middleware working. I eventually gave up and tried  [asset-rack](https://github.com/techpines/asset-rack) which I was also unable to get working until I started using this fork: https://github.com/techpines/asset-rack/pull/76

Frustrated that the pull request for the asset-rack fork had been sitting around for 11 months I ended up just writing my own static file middleware called [Electricity](https://www.npmjs.org/package/electricity) that supports Sass among some other nice to have features.